# Cannot activate SharePoint Publishing Feature

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, feature, feature-activation

despite placing the following code in my onet.xml, the publishing feature is not activated.

```
<Feature ID="A392DA98-270B-4e85-9769-04C0FDE267AA">
<!-- PublishingPrerequisites -->
</Feature>

<Feature ID="7C637B23-06C4-472d-9A9A-7C175762C5C4">
<!-- ViewFormPagesLockDown -->
</Feature>

<Feature ID="AEBC918D-B20F-4a11-A1DB-9ED84D79C87E">
<!-- PublishingResources -->
<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Property Key="AllowRss" Value="false"/>
<Property Key="SimplePublishing" Value="false" />
</Properties>
</Feature>

<!-- Publishing Infrastructure Feature --> 
<Feature ID="F6924D36-2FA8-4f0b-B16D-06B7250180FA"/>
```

I need this feature to be activated, because I have a feature-receiver which executes some  code dependent on the feature.

Comment: what SharePoint version you are using? What error you getting when activating the publishing feature?

Comment: Try and place it at the top and see what happens.

Comment: SharePoint 2010, when activating the publishing feature theres isn't error. I can activate the feature in Site Collection Administration : Features

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are experiencing a combination of issues:

- the actual [Publishing features are many for each Web](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsnoiwb/archive/2010/01/07/features-and-their-guid-s-in-sp2010.aspx)),
  which must all properly be activated, as Web features (is this the
  section where you have the GUID added?). But the only one you need 
  to actually add in the WebFeatures is **SharePoint Server Publishing 
  (94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb)** as the others are hidden, and 
  normally activated automatically.
- You need to ensure that in the SiteFeatures you have the SharePoint
  Server **Publishing Infrastructure 
  (f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa**) - do you have this here?